# Please Translate this from C# to SQL in plain english

Tags: c#, sql

Can someone please break this c# down in english?  Is it possible to add a join in there somehow?

```
return db.Providers.Where(n => n.LastName.StartsWith(prefixText)).OrderBy(
       n=>n.LastName).Select(n => n.LastName).Take(count).ToArray();
```

Thanks.

Comment: -1 For being so unclear with your question and your goal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SQL query is probably something like:

```
SELECT LastName FROM Providers
WHERE LastName LIKE 'PrefixText%'
ORDER BY LastName
LIMIT count; -- This may be TOP in MS SQL or ROWNUM in Oracle
```

Which means:

Give me all rows from the table `Providers` where the `LastName` column starts with *PrefixText* (whatever that variable contains).  I want them sorted alphabetically by the `LastName` column, and I only want the first *count* rows (i.e., if `count` was equal to 50, you'd get up to 50 rows)

Sure, you can do a `JOIN`.  You can refer to another table within your `Where` expression:

```
db.Providers.Where(n => n.ProviderGroup.ADgroup == 'Active Dir Group')
```

And the framework will automatically *join in* `ADgroup` for you, provided your model provides the necessary relationships between your tables.

Comment: `select LastName`, not `select *`.

Comment: @JoeEnos - Yup, good catch.

Comment: Is it possible to add a join from db.providers to another table? what would that look like in c#?

Comment: @Sj14420 - Just refer to a property in your model that has a reference to another table.  It will add in the necessary *joins* for you.

Comment: I'm not sure how to do that..

Comment: ok, that helps alot!  I'll see if I can make it work.  Thanks EVERYONE!

Comment: last question, how do I write two where arguments?

db.Providers.Where(n => n.LastName.StartsWith(prefixText) && n => n.AD_Groups == AdGroup

Comment: @Sj14420 - Almost.  `db.Providers.Where(n => n.LastName.StartsWith(prefixText) && n.AD_Groups == AdGroup)`

Answer (score 0):

Get x number of last name's of all Providers whose LastName starts with the text in the variable prefixText, in ascending alphabetical order.

Comment: Thank you!  Is it possible to add a join from db.providers to another table?  what would that look like?

Comment: @Sj14420, what kind of join are you looking for? Inner, left, right, or full?

Comment: inner.  something like join ADGroups ad on ad.providerid = prov.providerid

Answer (score 0):

This will return an array containing `count` last names, ordered in increasing alphabetical order, and starting with `prefixText`.

Answer (score 0):

This is the corresponding SQL code:

```
select top @count LastName from Providers
where LastName like '+@prefixText+%'
order by LastName
```

Why do you need a `join` here?

**Update:**

Per the OP comment:

> I need a `join` for limit the results of an Ajax auto extender...

You don't need a join for limiting the results in the Ajax Auto Extender, just use SQL's `top` clause or LINQ's `Take` method, just like you're doing right now:

`db.Providers.Where(n => n.LastName.StartsWith(prefixText)).OrderBy(
       n=>n.LastName).Select(n => n.LastName).Take(count).ToArray();`

Comment: I need a join to limit the results of an Ajax auto extender...

Comment: Please look at my updated answer. Generally, you can do the limit operation in your query.

Comment: ok, but what if the thing I need to limit by is in a different table than the lastname?

Comment: I'm sorry, can you explain?

Comment: Sure, I have a providers table that has the lastname column which is what will end up being returned to the textbox.  Then I have an AD groups table.  I only want to display provider names that are associated with the user's logged in AD group which I capture as a session variable.  

So the SQL would be something like :
   select lastname from providers p join adgroup ad on ad.providergroupid = p.providergroupid where ad.ADgroup = 'Active Dir Group'

Comment: I think you _really_ want to read about sql `join`: [http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html)

Comment: thanks Yair, but I'm pretty good on SQL..its just getting the join to work in the return statement of c#.  Perhaps Linq would be a solution, but I havnt had much success getting linq to work with the ajax autoextend control..